# Motivation for Catalan's Aliquot Sequence Conjecture

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Catalan's Aliquot Sequence Conjecture states that every aliquot sequence ends in a prime, a repeating aliquot sequence (a set of sociable numbers) or a perfect number.

In my naive mind I can't help to wonder how this conjecture is motivated?
Why do we guess that it does not exist any divergent Aliquot Sequence?

Comment: Catalan worked a long time ago. I suspect that most living number theorists who have thought about the problem expect there are infinitely many divergent aliquot sequences.

Answer (score 1):

The 1975 paper [What Drives an Aliquot Sequence?](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-129/S0025-5718-1975-0384669-X/) may be of interest: the authors have "conjectured that an infinite number of aliquot sequences are unbounded" despite offering a proof that one common way for sequences to increase monotonically cannot continue indefinitely.  (They had much more data to conjecture with than Catalan, of course.  40 years later we have even more, but I don't know the current state of this problem.)